# Python - How to choose line in console to read from

Tags: python, input

As I understand it, input() reads a new line every time it's called, but is there a way for me to make it read, say, the third line of input and then read the second line of input without first storing the second line?

Comment: Define storing, I am not sure what you mean. Remember the input of the past?

Comment: I know one way to do it would be:

Comment: (Sorry, I clicked enter by mistake) Anyway, I know that I can get the first three lines and store the second as a variable. But can I choose between different lines without having to store the line as a string and using it later?

Comment: I am not sure in what case  this would be required but anyway, the `input` captures a whole line, meaning pressing "enter" ends the reading.
skipping a line is thus impossible, not multi-line input.
However, you can do so when reading from a file but then again I see no reason to need this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The `input()` function takes data from standard input stream and returns it somewhere in your code. Then the contents of standard input stream is forgotten.